# Categories in foursquare checkin pushes are partially translated

Tags: api, push, real-time, foursquare

I'm working with the [foursquare Real-Time API](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime) and now I have a question regarding the JSON of the push for a check-in. More precisely it's regarding the category names of the venue categories.
My iPhone language setting is german and hence the foursquare app is using a german layout. On a foursquare push to my server the fields name, pluralName and shortName are translated to german whereas the categories in the field parents appear in english (see examples below).

In my opinion it doesn't make sense to use translations of the category (especially when only one part is translated :-)). Do you think that this should be the regular behavior of the API?
At the end it's really hard to work with the categories since the ID is only embedded for the top category.

Would be great if someone has a hint or can confirm it.

```
{
   …[snip]…,
    "categories": [
        {
            "icon": "https://foursquare.com/img/categories/building/home.png", 
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d103941735", 
            "name": "Zuhause (privat)", 
            "pluralName": "Zuhause (privat)", 
            "shortName": "Zuhause",
            "parents": [
                "Residences"
            ],
            "primary": true
        }
    ],
   …[snip]…
}
```

vs.
untranslated (english):

```
{
   …[snip]…,
    "categories": [
        {
            "icon": "https://foursquare.com/img/categories/building/home.png", 
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d103941735", 
            "name": "Home (private)", 
            "pluralName": "Homes (private)", 
            "shortName": "Home",
            "parents": [
                "Residences"
            ],
            "primary": true
        }
    ],
   …[snip]…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by using an unversioned API call.

Your calls to the API should support a version parameter of the form `&v=20130115` (the date) to ensure that you are receiving up-to-date content. Otherwise, you will receive content from old versions of the API.

In the latest version of the API, the parents attribute is absent from the category JSON, and you should use the venues/categories API call (which is fully translated) to build your category hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah, it's right that the venues/categories are translated. But my problem (and examples) above are the push messages that foursquare sends on a user checkin to a connected app via [User Push API](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime).

Comment: I understand - thanks for identifying this issue. We've pushed a fix, you should start seeing these values translated by tomorrow.

Comment: Wow, cool. Thank you very much :-) I'll check it at the end of the week. Great support!